# Console in electronjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am creating code editor with electron.js. I would like that user will be able to open console in code editor(not browser console but cmd ). I looked it up in google and i didnt find any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to spawn proces you node's [process module](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html).

And if you want to integrate terminal more deeply like in vs code you would have to redirect stdin, stdout and probably stderror.

It's all described in node documentation.